# service Layer and transactions

Tags: grails, service, transactions

I have 2 DBs and the service method I am using passes in the object from DB 1 and attempts to retrieve and process hasMany items from the 2nd DB.  When I wrap the process in an .withTransaction the method works.

```
def buildApoMap( Apo pApo ) {           
  def lResults = [:]
  Apo.withTransaction() {
  if ( pApo ) {
    lResults.apo = [ id: pApo.id, apoId: pApo.apoId, 
          accountName: pApo.account?.accountName, 
          subProgram: [ id: pApo.subProgram?.id, name: pApo.subProgram?.name],
          eventCount: pApo.events?.toList().size ]

   if ( pApo.events ) {
      lResults.apo.events = pApo.events.collect { lEvent ->
            [id: lEvent.id, eventReferenceId: lEvent.eventReferenceId, 
            sellingMethod: lEvent.sellingMethod?.toString(),
            accountCommissionMethod: lEvent.accountCommissionMethod]
    }
  }
    }
  }
  return lResults
}
```

When I declare

```
 static transactional = true
```

The method fails with the following error message

```
ERROR 2014-01-10 08:44:48,084 [JDBCExceptionReporter] [http-bio-8080-exec-4] [unknown 8:44:47 AM|] - Connection is closed.
 ERROR 2014-01-10 08:44:48,091 [ApoRestController] [http-bio-8080-exec-4] [unknown 8:44:47 AM|] - Unexpected exception while processing Rest request to search for APOs.
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection: [com.company.Apo.events#7]
at com.company.ApoService$$EOSYMFqe.buildApoMap(ApoService.groovy:240)
at com.company.ApoRestController$_search_closure2.doCall(ApoRestController.groovy:78)
at com.company.ApoRestController.search(ApoRestController.groovy:77)
at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:65)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:312)
... 7 more
```

Any Ideas?  We will be doing this a lot.  Would like to not have to wrap each method in its own transaction.

Comment: Have you tried using an @Transactional annotation?

Comment: I think you need to use something like the atomikos plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/atomikos) to support a transaction across multiple databases.

Comment: @dspies you're right that 2PC is the answer, and the Atomikis plugin provides that - make your comment an answer so we can upvote it :)

Comment: Thanks @BurtBeckwith, actually picked this up from your great book Programming Grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use something like the atomikos plugin (http://www.grails.org/plugin/atomikos) to support a transaction across multiple databases.